# How to force string type or ignore type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

The following code

```
<Image src={user?.profilePictureUrl} alt={user?.name} />
```

gives this error

> Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string |
> StaticImport'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string |
> StaticImport'.

The `user` objects type is:

```
const user: User | null | undefined
```

**Question**

Somehow I need to tell TypeScript that an empty string is acceptable or that it should accept any. How can I do that?

Comment: `user?.profilePictureUrl as string` might do the trick, would `Image` not allow an undefined string? You could also use null coalsce if you want to always provide a value `user?.profilePictureUrl ?? "path_to_placeholder_image"`

Comment: Great! I'll write up an answer for future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) for this:

```js
  <Image src={user?.profilePictureUrl as string} alt={user?.name} />
```

But we aware that type assertion typically just masks the warning as you're telling the compiler you know more than it does.

A perhaps more sure-fire way, if you don't necessarily have control over the `Image` component is to use [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing), as you can then always provide a valid value for `src`:

```js
  <Image src={user?.profilePictureUrl ?? "path_to_fallback_image"} alt={user?.name} />
```